# Эмуляция микрофона (+ микшинг из двух устройств)

Tags: c#, аудио

Есть одновременно и простая и сложная задача:

1. Нужно сЭмулировать микрофон в ОС.
2. Звук на него подавать из микшера винды + из реального микрофона одновременно. + возможность настроить сдвиг один относительно второго вперед и назад.

Если есть готовое решение которое НЕ нужно писать самому -- так же подходят. VAC(Virtual Audio Cable) не подходит. Он почему-то с моей звучкой не работает.

Все что я имею сейчас это:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace SoundApp
{
    public class AudioCable
    {
        private WaveOut _wvOut = null;

        private DirectSoundOut _output = null;
        private WaveIn _sourceStreamIn = null;
        private WaveOut _sourceStreamOut = null;

        public void InitDevices(string fromDevice, string toDevice)
        {
            Dispose();

            _sourceStreamIn = new WaveIn();
            _sourceStreamOut = new WaveOut();
            _output = new DirectSoundOut();

            if (fromDevice.Contains("INPUT"))
            {
                var tmp = fromDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("INPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                _sourceStreamIn.DeviceNumber = tmpDeviceNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("OUTPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                _sourceStreamOut.DeviceNumber = tmpDeviceNumber;
            }

            Guid deviceGuid;
            if (toDevice.Contains("INPUT"))
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("INPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(tmpDeviceNumber);
                deviceGuid = deviceInfo.ManufacturerGuid;
            }
            else
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("OUTPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(tmpDeviceNumber);
                deviceGuid = deviceInfo.ManufacturerGuid;
            }
            _output = new DirectSoundOut(deviceGuid);
        }

        public void PlaySound()
        {
            WaveInProvider waveIn = null;

            if (_sourceStreamIn != null)
            {
                waveIn = new WaveInProvider(_sourceStreamIn);
            }
            else if (_sourceStreamOut != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Sorry, not supported right now");
                //waveIn = new WaveInProvider(_sourceStreamOut);
            }

            _output.Init(waveIn);
            _output.Play();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _sourceStreamIn = null;
            _sourceStreamOut = null;

            if (_output != null)
            {
                if (_output.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    _output.Stop();
                }

                _output.Dispose();
                _output = null;
            }
        }

        public string[] GetAudioDevices()
        {
            var devices = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
                WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i);
                devices.Add($"INPUT: {i}     | {deviceInfo.ProductName}");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < WaveOut.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
                WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
                devices.Add($"OUTPUT: {i} | {deviceInfo.ProductName}");
            }

            return devices.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

И соурс формы:

```
namespace SoundApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AudioCable _ac = new AudioCable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cBoxSource.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cBoxTarget.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            cBoxSource.Items.AddRange(_ac.GetAudioDevices());
            cBoxTarget.Items.AddRange(_ac.GetAudioDevices());
        }

        private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ac.InitDevices(cBoxSource.SelectedItem.ToString(), cBoxTarget.SelectedItem.ToString());
            _ac.PlaySound();
        }
    }
}
```

Для начала я пытаюсь стримить микрофонный звук в аутпут девайс. Но это не работает.

Мои вопросы:

1. Почему не работает? Код валидный и ошибок нету.
2. Похоже что нету возможности стримить  outputDevice sound на inputDevice с помощью NAudio. Есть ли какой-нить hack для этого? Устроит, даже, с большой задержкой в секунду-две.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [виртуальное аудио-устройство](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:H9QiKRRLJtEJ:vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm%20&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru&lr=lang_en%7Clang_ru) или [напиши своё](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/windows-driver-kit-wdk-80-e3161626).
А дальше [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/MixingWaveProvider32.cs) в руки и смешивай как угодно.